# query to get sum and distinct in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a data in table like this:

```
==================== 
class | in   | out 
==================== 
1       35      5
2       37      3
```

and i want the result like this :

```
============================ 
Info  |   class    | total
      | 1   |   2  |
============================ 
in      35    37       72
out     5      3        8
```

so how to make a query in mysql to get those results?

please help me, I've tried many times but have not been successful

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine two pivots with a `UNION`.

```
SELECT "in" AS Info,
       MAX(CASE WHEN class = 1 THEN `in` END) AS class1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN class = 2 THEN `in` END) AS class2,
       SUM(`in`) AS total
FROM yourTable
UNION
SELECT "out" AS Info,
       MAX(CASE WHEN class = 1 THEN `out` END) AS class1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN class = 2 THEN `out` END) AS class2,
       SUM(`out`) AS total
FROM yourTable
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e4ba/4)

Comment: ups, im so so sorry barmar... :)